# Play framework - pass parameter to Writes and Reads

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

Is there a way to pass parameter into a Writes to I will be able to control they way the JsValue is written?

This is how it looks right now:

```
implicit val myClassWrites = new Writes[MyClass] {
    override def writes(l: MyClass): JsValue = Json.obj("a" -> l.a, "b" -> l.b)
}
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
implicit val myClassWrites = new Writes[MyClass] (extended: Option[Boolean]) {
    override def writes(l: MyClass): JsValue = {
          extended match{
             case true => //do something
             case false => //do something else
          }
    }
}
```

Is there an elegant way to achieve this? or something similar?

I managed do implement this need with Reads like this(dropping the implicit):

```
def myClassReads(c: String) : Reads[MyClass] = (
  Reads.pure(c) and
  (JsPath \ "a").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "b").read[String]
) (MyClass.apply _)
```

And then when I want to use the reads (usually in the controller when I want to validate the body of the request) I do:

```
request.body.validate[MyClass](MyClass.myClassReads("foo")).fold(
    errors => //
    myClass=> // do domething
)
```

So the Writes is still a mystery.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `implicit` parameters. See code below:

```
case class Extended(b: Boolean)

object MyClass {

 implicit def MyClassWrites(implicit extended: Extended): Writes[MyClass] = new Writes[MyClass] {
     def writes(l: MyClass) =
          if (extended.b) JsString("foo")
          else JsString("bar")
    }
}
```

And then use like this

```
implicit var extd = Extended(true)

println(Json.toJson(myClass)) // foo

extd = Extended(false)

println(Json.toJson(myClass)) // bar
```

Comment: In my view using implicits to configure behavior is a big part of the reason they get such a bad rap in Scala. Everybody does it, but [I wish we would do it a little less](https://github.com/travisbrown/circe/blob/master/DESIGN.md)—especially in a case like this, where tracking down the call site and finding the implicit that was in scope could get really annoying.

Comment: Thanks! using implicit params indeed will solve my problem, but I agree with @TravisBrown, I don't like using implicit params in such cases, where after a while it become pretty cryptic to understand from where do I get this magic param. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I don't know how exactly you will be use `Writes`, but in case  of using method `Json.toJson(o: T)(tjs: Writes[T])` you may define `Writes` as method like `def myClassWrites(extended: Boolean): Writes[MyClass] = ....` and use like `Json.toJson(myClass)(myClassWrites(true /*false*/))` (or directly `myClassWrites(true).writes(myClass)`). I understand your `Reads` usage, but how you will be use `Writes`?

Comment: This is exactly what I did @MrRontgen